# What type of websites does memcached speed up

Tags: performance, apache, memcached, nginx

I have read this article about [400% boost of your website](http://www.igvita.com/2008/02/11/nginx-and-memcached-a-400-boost/). This is done by a combination of nginx and memcached. The how-to part of this website is quite good, but i mis the part where it says to what types of websites this applies.

I know nginx is a http engine, I need no explanation for that.

I thought memcached had something to do with caching database result. However i don't understand what this has to do with the http request, can someone please explain that to me.

Another question I have is for what types of websites is this used. I have a website where the important part of the website consist of data that changes often. Often being minutes.

Will this method still apply to me, or should I just stick with the basic boring setup of apache and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

memcached is a generic memory data cache. It's probably most commonly used to cache database objects, but it can accomplish a large number of other tasks.

The particular article you linked is describing how to use nginx in place of the Mongrel httpd usually used for the Rails web framework. memcached is being used to cache the results of dynamic pages that use querystrings to generate the dynamic content; in this specific use case, it appears the page will generate identical results with an identical querystring each time, so significant performance gains can be had by simply bypassing appserver generation and caching the rendered HTML in memcached.

Despite the somewhat overhyped headline, the article is not giving a use case that is appropriate for all (or even most) dynamic web pages. But if you have pages which require a lot of computation and return the same results with the same parameters for all users (public search results are a good example), this solution will give you significant performance improvement.

Comment: So if I understand correctly every single html character of the desired website has to be the same. For example the url http://mydomain.com/articles/get-some-article has to be the same everytime a user requests is. If there are rapid changes on this article the whole setup would be useless.

Comment: Right. This is for pages that don't change at all between invocations as long as the parameters are the same. Note that pages which include, say, advertising in an iframe can still use this mechanism, since the iframe code will be static but the page loaded by the iframe can change.

Answer (score 1):

**From the memcached [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ):**

> Adding memcached support to your
>   application can be a lot of work.
>   MySQL has a handy query cache feature
>   that will automatically cache the
>   results of your SQL queries, making
>   them way faster on repeat runs. How
>   does memcached compare to this?
>   MySQL's query cache is centralized, so
>   its benefits are seen by all servers
>   connecting to it.
>
> - MySQL's query cache flushes as soon    as you modify a table. You can store
>     a memcached item for a minimum amount 
>     of time, but if you get a lot of
>     write traffic, MySQL's query cache
>     will be constantly expiring all
>     entries
> - MySQL's query cache has scalability    issues for many CPUs. It adds a
>     global lock, and gets slower as it
>     has to flush more queries.
> - You can't store arbitrary data    objects into the cache. You can build 
>     much more efficient caches with
>     memcached. Run several separate
>     queries to build a user object, build 
>     the user object, then cache that.
>     MySQL's query cache can help small
>     sites, but can do more harm than good 
>     at scale.
> - Memory is limited to how much spare    RAM you have on your database. It's
>     much nicer to give your database more 
>     RAM to cache data :) With memcached
>     you spread out the cluster wherever
>     you have spare memory, so you can
>     cache much much more.

Comment: Thank you for copying these parts of the FAQ. Memcached has some good features. But this still does not explain for what types of websites the article in the question can be applied to. In the article memcached is used with a 5 minute setup. I doubt that can ever be true. I have read these faq's of memcached and know it is not that easy to set up, thats why I asked the question what the article describes exactly.